# presentation.close Invalid request: Cannot perform this action with a modal dialog showing

Tags: vba, powerpoint

To loop thru some presentatons my powerpoint VBA code uses a UserForm that
has some previous/next buttons to go back and forth between presentations.

When the next button is clicked I am trying to close the currently loaded presentation like this:

```
Dim pres as Presentation
...
pres.close
```

which leads to the error message:

```
Runtime Error -2147188160 (80048240)
Presentation (unknown member): Invalid request: Cannot perform this action
with a modal dialog showing.
```

Even if the userform is called with

```
form.show vbModeLess
```

**What can be done to fix this behavior?**

My environment is Powerpoint 2011 for Mac 14.7.3 but I assume this will also happen on Windows.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for code running in PresentationA to close PresentationB but if the code (and your form) are in PresentationA and you're trying to close PresentationA, that won't work.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg - thank you for looking into this. I have a file macros.pptm which has the userform and opens all the other presentations. As you say "it should be no problem" but in my environment it is. Unfortunately i do not know of any way to report such bugs to Microsoft.

Comment: Things sometimes happen in Mac PPT VBA that a) don't happen in Windows PPT and b) make no sense.  In your error handler, add MsgBox UserForms.Count ... make sure that the number of forms it reports is what you THINK it should be. Oh, and be sure to restart MacOS. Sometimes PPT can leave invisible copies of itself behind that cause all sorts of mischief. And OS restart will clear those out.